# How to Write Backspace code for textfield in java application?

Tags: java, swing

This is my simple button what code I have to write to make it a backspace button.

```
        JButton btnBackspace = new JButton("B");
        btnBackspace.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            }
        });
        btnBackspace.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 22));
        btnBackspace.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Image btBack = new 
        ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/b.png")).getImage();
        btnBackspace.setIcon(new ImageIcon(btBack));
        btnBackspace.setBounds(121, 145, 97, 63);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBackspace);;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample code of a backspace button that will erase text from the assigned text field
here -> first the text is saved into backspace variable the according to the length of text -1 is done to erase the text and then text is assigned to base textfeild again

```
JButton btnBackspace = new JButton("\uF0E7");
        btnBackspace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String backspace = null;
                if(txtResult.getText().length()>0) {
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(txtResult.getText());
                    strBuilder.deleteCharAt(txtResult.getText().length()-1);
                    backspace = strBuilder.toString();
                    txtResult.setText(backspace);
                }
            }
        });
        btnBackspace.setFont(new Font("Wingdings", Font.BOLD, 22));
        btnBackspace.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Image btBack = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/b.png")).getImage();
        btnBackspace.setIcon(new ImageIcon(btBack));
        btnBackspace.setBounds(121, 145, 97, 63);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBackspace);
```

Comment: (1-)  1) This will only remove text from the end of the text field. 2) Don't use setText(...) to delete a character. This will generate incorrect events for the text field. Swing text components use a Document to contain the text. Updates to the text should be done via the Document.

Answer (score 2):

Text components use a `Document` to hold the data. Changes to the Document are made by using the `insertString(...)` or `remove(...)` methods.

If you want to remove text from a specific text field then you can use:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Back Space");
button.addActionListener((e) ->
{
    try
    {
        int offset = textField.getCaretPosition();
        Document doc = textField.getDocument();
        doc.remove(offset - 1, 1);
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
});
```

Or you can write a generic listener. The following example will remove text from the last text component that had focus before the button was clicked:

```
Action backSpace = new TextAction("Back Space")
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
            int offset = component.getCaretPosition();
            Document doc = component.getDocument();
            doc.remove(offset-1, 1);
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
    }
};

JButton button = new JButton(backSpace);
```